# ng-reflect-ng-for-of Angular 9

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I tried to make a *ngFor but appear this: ng-reflect-ng-for-of. When use de console log the variable work good.

**Code html:**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let cabecera of cabeceras">hello {{ cabecara }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

**Code .ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductoService } from '../../services/Producto.Service';


@Component({
  selector: 'tabla-producto',
  templateUrl: './tabla-producto.component.html'
})

export class TablaProductoComponent implements OnInit { 

cabeceras: string[];

@Input()  productos: any[] = [];


  constructor(private producto: ProductoService) {
    this.cabeceras = ['Id Producto', 'Nombre', 'Precio', 'Stock', 'Nombre Categoria'];
  }


  // Todo lo que pongamos aquí abajo, se ejecutará al cargar la página
  ngOnInit(){
    this.producto.getProducto().subscribe((data: any) => {
     // console.log("imprime objeto data")
     // console.log(data);
      this.productos = data;

      console.log("imprime objeto productos")
      console.log(this.productos);
    });
  }

}
```

**Image console**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo

```
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let cabecera of cabeceras">hello {{ cabecara }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

you have written `cabecara` and not `cabecera`